# Sort elements in iframe from parent. (Prototype + Scriptaculous)

Tags: iframe, prototypejs, jquery-ui-sortable, scriptaculous

I am trying to sort elements in an iframe from the parent frame using prototype + scriptaculous. I am receiving the following error when I try to create the sortable object:

"element.identify is not a function"

Firebug is stating it is failing on the following line of code from dragdrop.js (Line 734)

"this.sortables[element.identify()] = options;"

Due to the setup I need all code running from the parent, not the iframe. 
My function looks like this:

```
function setSortable(){
//Create sortables
var doc = top.frames[0].document;
var sideContent = doc.getElementById('side-bar');
var mainContent = doc.getElementById('main-content');

if(sideContent){
    Sortable.create(sideContent, {tag:'table'});
}

if(mainContent){
    Sortable.create(mainContent, {tag:'table'});
}
```

}

Is it possible to run the scriptaculous code from the parent frame without referencing it in the iframe page?

Your help would be much appreciated.